# Create a subvector from regularly spaced elements of another vector

Tags: c++, vector

Very simple question: is there a smart way of creating a subvector from regularly spaced elements of another vector with the STL?

In short, is it possible to write the following code with a STL algorithm:

```
int inc = 2;
std::vector<double> v_origin;
std::vector<double> v_dest;

for (int i = 0; i < v_origin.size(); i+= inc)
    v_dest.push_back(v_origin[i]);
```

Like I would write in Matlab or Python something like:

```
v_dest = v_origin[0:inc:end];
```

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. There may be more performant ways of filling the destination vector (pre-allocated size?, std::copy) but as far as I know, no direct way of accomplishing what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general solution, you could define a [stride iterator](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/cplusplus/0596007612/science-and-mathematics/cplusplusckbk-chp-11-sect-13#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTA1OTYwMDc2MTIvNDE5). If you use Boost.Range, then it already as a [`strided` range adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html).

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

int main()
{
    int inc = 2;
    std::vector<double> v_origin;
    std::vector<double> v_dest;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i)
        v_origin.push_back(i);

    boost::copy(v_origin | boost::adaptors::strided(2),
                std::back_inserter(v_dest));
    // ^ In Python:    v_dest[] = v_origin[::2]

    boost::copy(v_dest, std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(Creating another answer as it's a different approach.)

If you just want to push_back a strided slice of another container, and does not intend to use that `lst[a:b:c]` concept anywhere else, it is probably easier to write a generic `copy`-like function:

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
void copy_strided(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end,
                  OutputIterator result, size_t stride)
{
   assert(stride >= 1);

   for (size_t i = stride; begin != end; ++ i, ++ begin)
   {
      if (i == stride)
      {
         *result = *begin;
         ++ result;
         i = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

[Usage](http://ideone.com/WaQ1X):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int inc = 2;
    std::vector<double> v_origin;
    std::vector<double> v_dest;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i)
        v_origin.push_back(i);

    copy_strided(v_origin.begin(), v_origin.end(), std::back_inserter(v_dest), inc);

    std::copy(v_dest.begin(), v_dest.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct RemoveNth
{
    RemoveNth(int incin)
    {
        count = 0;
        inc = incin;
    }

    bool operator()(double x )
    {
        return count++ % inc == 0;
    }

    int count;
    int inc;
};

int main()
{

    int inc = 2;
    std::vector<double> v_origin;
    std::vector<double> v_dest;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100; ++i )
        v_origin.push_back( i );

    v_dest  = v_origin;
    RemoveNth helper(3);
    std::vector<double>::iterator newend = 
         std::remove_if (v_dest.begin() , v_dest.end(), helper); 
    v_dest.erase( newend , v_dest.end() );

    return 0;
}
```

Something like above might work.

In C++11 you can use **std::copy_if** and instead of the separate functor you can use inline lambdas like so

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void copynth( T begin , T end , U dest , int n )
{
    int count = 0;
    std::copy_if( begin , end , dest ,
        [&count,n]( double x )
    {
        return count++ % n == 0;
    });
}

int main()
{

    int inc = 2;
    std::vector<double> v_origin;
    std::vector<double> v_dest;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100; ++i )
        v_origin.push_back( i );

    int count = 0;
    copynth( v_origin.begin() , v_origin.end() , std::back_inserter(v_dest) , 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There does not exist anything in the standard library that is meant for this task specifically.

Below is my own generic implementation. There is a separate implementation for random access iterator and for other input iterators.

```
#include <iterator>

namespace detail {
template <class SourceIter, class OutIter>
void strided_copy_aux(SourceIter from, SourceIter to, OutIter out, unsigned step, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    SourceIter end = (to - from) / step * step + from;
    for (; from < end; from += step ) {
        *out = *from;
    }
    if (end < to) {
        *out = *end;
    }
}

template <class SourceIter, class OutIter>
void strided_copy_aux(SourceIter from, SourceIter to, OutIter out, unsigned step, std::input_iterator_tag)
{
    while (from != to) {
        *out = *from;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i != step; ++i) {
            ++from;
            if (from == to) break;
        }
    }
}
}

template <class SourceIter, class OutIter>
void strided_copy(SourceIter from, SourceIter to, OutIter out, unsigned step)
{
    detail::strided_copy_aux(from, to, out, step, typename std::iterator_traits<SourceIter>::iterator_category());
}
```

Usage example: http://ideone.com/1Wmq3

Comment: Why not use advance on the iterator and provide one implemenation??

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: You can't advance a random access iterator by, say 5, if you don't know it won't go beyond the end iterator. On the other hand, you can't calculate the number of advances to be made with other types of iterators. (With input iterators, the latter would be completely impossible.)